# Facedetection on video: CL_EXEC_STATUS_ERROR_FOR_EVENTS_IN_WAIT_LIST error

Tags: opencv, memory-management, opencl, video-processing, face-detection

I am trying to run face detection on a 5 minute 720P video. I am using opencv API and opencl kernels to do my job. When I try to run the program, it runs fine for intial few number of frames. But after some frames, it gives me an error

*OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (CL_EXEC_STATUS_ERROR_FOR_EVENTS_IN_WAIT_LIST) in openCLMemcpy2D, file /opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/ocl/src/initialization.cpp, line 466*

Sometimes I get this error after processing 200 frames, sometimes I get this error after 2000 frames.
Can anyone suggest me why I am facing this error and what could be a possible solution? I searched internet but did not find anythng.

**UPDATE:** I executed the program on my desktop PC which has a AMD APU. The whole machine freezed after processing some frame. I also applied clFinish after each kernel to make sure teh synchronization. Even though, the system freezed. So, it is not a synchronization issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that OpenCL event, which is in wait list of some kernel, has invalid status.  Kernel, being issued to Command Queue can't wait for it's completion. Usually this happens due to lack of proper synchronization, so the number of processed frames is a matter of luck.

As OpenCV is pretty big library, not so easy to debug, the easiest way to go, in my opinion, is to collect runtime profile & see if tasks in Command Queues are going in right order. You can do it with profiler, which is usually shipped with OpenCL SDK by vendor (like Nvidia Visual Profiler or AMD CodeXL).

Comment: thanks for your reply. if synchronization is the issue, in that case, if I use clFinish after each kernel call then that should solve my problem. I will do this test. But I guess it is related to memory. If I remove the last kernel call in the program, then the program runs fine. And the error occurs when I try to transfer the image matrix to OclMatrix. Could you tell me how I can find the profiling info? The only thing I find which prints the kernel execution time.

Comment: It depends on what platform are you using.

Comment: I am using arndale board with Mali GPU. My opencv is compiled for arm. Does that help?

Comment: I executed the program on my desktop PC which has a AMD APU. The whole machine freezed after processing some frame. I also applied clFinish after each kernel to make sure teh synchronization. Even though, the system freezed. So, it is not a synchronization issue.

Comment: I have updated the post with the detect function that calls the kernels.

Comment: My advice is to allocate memory outside of the frame processing loop. I don't know how cl::Mat manages memory, but anyway, it potentially brings you a big overhead on memory objects (de)allocation.

Comment: Thats not possible. Each time the the memory is allocated based on some calculation inside the loop. Different loops have different sized memory allocation. As far as I know oclMatrix has a destructor to release memory if it goes out of scope.

Comment: Such algorithm looks too complicated from the debugging point of view. May be you should try to allocate maximal available memory amount and then just tune NDRange size? Try to dice up complex problem into bunch of simple ones.